# How do I extrude diagonally?

Tags: modeling

[image]

The picture above is done by pressing ggc(shortcut of move). By the way, what should I do when extrude?

[image]

I want to draw like number 2 in line with the first line angle.
But if I press g twice and c, the guide line comes out to the diagonal angle, but extrude doesn't come out.

[image]

It's not a straight line for me to do without a guide line.

[image]

Comment: um, I'm not entirely sure what your question is, could you elaborate a lot more?

Comment: I'd like to draw a line extended. There is no guide line for extrude. Added explanation. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: ok, thanks for explaining more, I think I understand now. Do you mind sharing your file so I can see what is going on here?  you can use this link:https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I uploaded the file. thank you